# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Bioinformatics Stack Exchange's [first moderator election](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Kamil S Jaron] [image: gringer]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6133728716783616).

Comment: Yay! Congratulations to you both!

Comment: JNat, it appears that the first hyperlink is not working!

Comment: Looks like someone fixed it in the meantime, @user1271772

Comment: Thank you for your trust folks <3

Comment: Thank you. Those results are quite the motivator for me!

Comment: Congratulations @gringer and @Kamil! It was a privilege being a candidate alongside you guys and I know you'll be great mods. I look forward to working more with you!

Comment: Significantly belated congrats and a good response from @RamRS